# Trying to use PIL to resize an image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm getting this `ImportError`:

```
dlopen(/Users/owencharles/PycharmProjects/pythonProject3/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.cpython-310-darwin.so, 0x0002)
```

tried:

```
/Users/owencharles/PycharmProjects/pythonProject3/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.cpython-310-darwin.so`
```

(mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')

Comment: Please post code as text, not an image of text.

Comment: from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

window = Tk()
window.geometry("500x500")
window.title("Elite Makeovers Scheduling App")

elite_image = Image.open("Elite Makeovers App Photo.png")

resized = elite_image.resize((250, 250), Image.ANTIALIAS)

elite_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized)

window.mainloop()

Comment: from PIL import Image, ImageTk
  File "/Users/owencharles/PycharmProjects/pythonProject3/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 132, in <module>
    from . import _imaging as core
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/owencharles/PycharmProjects/pythonProject3/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.cpython-310-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Users/owencharles/PycharmProjects/pythonProject3/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.cpython-310-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64'))

Comment: I'm guessing you're using a new M1 Mac, but PIL hasn't been updated for the M1, at least not the version you are trying to use.

Comment: Yes I am. So is there another way I can size the image so it resizes while the user is making the window bigger with Python? By the way thanks for reaching out.

Comment: You could try installing Rosetta, or maybe installing the latest version of PIL.